# Prevent webpack mangling process.env variables

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

In a node library which is bundled by webpack 4, I want to use environment variables like `process.env.APP_NAME` which are passed to the end-user application (after the library being imported). I have tried to customize the `UglifyJsPlugin` and prevent mangling it, using this webpack configurations:

```
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        mangle: {
          reserved: ['process']
        }
      }
    })]
  }
```

But is't not working. I really wonder if this is possible at all. And then If I'm doing it in a right way.

Comment: have you tried setting `mangle` to `false`?